# How to prove that $\int_0^\infty (1/t \int_0^t \frac{f(s)}{s} ds )^p dt/t\le \int_0^\infty (\frac{f(t)}{t} )^p dt/t $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Set $1<p<\infty$, prove that for every mesurable function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$
$$\int_0^\infty \Big( \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t\frac{f(s)}{s}ds \Big)^p\frac{dt}{t}\le   \int_0^\infty \Big(\frac{f(t)}{t}  \Big)^p\frac{dt} {t}.$$

Hint: start from $f\in C^\infty_c(0,\infty)$.

I'm stuck with this exercise, can you help me or give me a hint?

Comment: May I ask about the source of this exercise?

Comment: It's an homework-exercise I encountered attending a real-analysis course.  It's not from a book.

Comment: A hopefully not too big hint: Use the Hölder inequality (with measure $d\mu(t)=\frac{dt}t$) on the function $\Phi(t)^p$, where $\Phi(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\frac{f(s)}{s}\,ds$.

Comment: To apply Holder in general i need the product of two functions under the integral, if $\Phi^p$ is the first one the other is simply $1$?

Comment: Or you could use $\Phi\cdot \Phi^{p-1}$...

Comment: Which exponent $q$ should I use applying Holder?

Comment: You should use $p$ for $\Phi$ (and thus the dual exponent for $\Phi^{p-1}$).

Comment: But i tried that and got a trivial identity, since the dual exponent is just $p/p-1$.

Comment: I now gave the complete answer. Please read line by line and try to finish from each line yourself if you want to learn as much as possible from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p>1$, $d\mu(t)=\frac{dt}{t}$ and
$$
\Phi(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\frac{f(s)}{s}\,ds.
$$
We note that we can write $\Phi(t)=\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\,dy$, and thus, by Fubini's theorem,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(t)^p\,d\mu(t)&=\int_0^{+\infty}\biggl[\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\,dy\biggr]\cdot\Phi(t)^{p-1}\,d\mu(t)\\
&=\int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\cdot\Phi(t)^{p-1}\,d\mu(t)\biggr]\,dy.
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, we invoke the Hölder inequality on the inner integral, and find that the integral in the right-hand side is bounded by (here $1/p+1/q=1$, so $q(p-1)=p$)
$$
\int_0^1\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Bigl(\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\Bigr)^p\,d\mu(t)\biggl]^{1/p}\cdot\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(t)^p\,d\mu(t)\biggr]^{1/q}\,dy
$$
By letting $s=ty$ in the integral in the left square bracket, we find that it is independent of $y$. But this means that the integrand is completely independent of $y$, and thus the $y$ integral just evaluates to $1$, and what we got is really
$$
\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Bigl(\frac{f(s)}{s}\Bigr)^p\,d\mu(s)\biggl]^{1/p}\cdot\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(t)^p\,d\mu(t)\biggr]^{1/q}
$$
If we now divide by
$$
\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(t)^p\,d\mu(t)\biggr]^{1/q}
$$
we find that
$$
\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Phi(t)^p\,d\mu(t)\biggr]^{1-1/q}\leq
\biggl[\int_0^{+\infty}\Bigl(\frac{f(s)}{s}\Bigr)^p\,d\mu(s)\biggl]^{1/p}.
$$
Raising both sides to $p$, we get the inequality we was about to prove.

This proof was in fact @JanG's idea (given in a private discussion we had). It is also worth mentioning that one can also prove the inequality by using the Minkowski inequality and some corollaries to it. The details are given in the book *Real Analysis* by Folland, see Theorem 6.20 and Exercise 29 on the page after.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now, I have two questions: first, why the exercise suggest to start from $f \in C^\infty_c$; second, reading the first lines of your proof I came up with a different method that I'm not sure if it is correct. I add now an answer with my alternative solution, can you see if it is acceptable?

Comment: I don't know about the $C_c^{+\infty}$ condition. Maybe it is easier to verify the conditions in the steps for that class (this is something I left out from my solution above), but that should be OK as is...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a variation on @mickep argument. Set $p>1$, now we have
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\frac{f(s)}{s}ds=\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}dy.$$
Applying Holder we get
$$\Big(\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}dy\Big)^p\le\int_0^1\Big(\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\Big)^pdy$$
and integrating on both sides in $dt/t$
$$\int_0^\infty\Big(\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}dy\Big)^p\frac{dt}{t}\le\int_0^\infty\int_0^1\Big(\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\Big)^pdy\frac{dt}{t}$$
Using Fubini on the right
$$\int_0^\infty\Big(\int_0^1\frac{f(ty)}{ty}dy\Big)^p\frac{dt}{t}\le\int_0^1\int_0^\infty\Big(\frac{f(ty)}{ty}\Big)^p\frac{dt}{t}dy$$
Finally setting $s=ty$ in the right hand side we get an integral independent from $y$ and the desired inequality.

Comment: I don't spot any error, and this is slightly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove this inequality if $f (x) /x$ were non-decreasing.

All we need to prove is $$\int_{0}^{t} \frac {f (s)} {s} ds \leqslant f(t).$$ Take $g (x) = f (x) / x$ wherever defined, then we should prove $$\int_{0}^{t} g (s) ds \leqslant t g(t).$$ Since $g$ is non-decreasing, we are done.

Comment: I like your approach. I just want to mention that for $f(s)=s^2/(1+s^2)$ one gets $\int_0^t f(s)/s\,ds=(1/2)\ln(1+t^2)$ which is not bounded by $f(t)$ for large $t$. So, to prove the inequality in general, this approach does not work.